# calling a function with a different way on native JS

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a solution for the basic structure of my code. I am trying to use less parenthesis or words. I don't know if there is a way or not but I want to ask :)

I am trying to create a dynamic object which changes when some other stuff changed. Basically, I have to use a function. I am here to abridge the way that I use.

Let me give you a working solution:

```
function mainFunction(object){

   // getElementById(object.id)
   // use object.date
   // use object.string

}

mainFunction (function(){return{  id:"varName",date: Date.now(), string:"test2"  }})
```

On this sample I am not happy with this commands:

```
mainFunction (function(){return{  
}})
```

Now, **question 1:**
Is there a way to use a short way to create a dynamic object?

//expected code

```
mainFunction{ id:"varName",date: Date.now(), string:"test2" };
```

-> date must be redefined on everytime that I call the object.
-> using date.now in quotation marks and call it with eval or Function isn't making sense.

**Question 2:**
is there a way to use the varName on the beginning even it is undefined?

//expected code

```
varName.mainFunction (date: Date.now(), string:"test2");
```

// expected result

```
{
if (typeof varName !=="undefined"){
 //create it.
}
// call the main function.
}
```

-> try, catch etc. don't work on here. Because I don't want to use try on the main code.

Thank you so much,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). I'm afraid it's not clear what you're trying to do here, and it's not clear which parts of the code you've shown are trying to *create* the thing you're asking about and which parts are trying to *use* it. Please [edit](/posts/56506454/edit) to clarify what you're trying to do.

Comment: Define your function to have a default parameter object that uses your default property values, `function main(obj={date:Date.now(),string:"test2"}){ console.log(obj); }` if the object you pass to the function doesnt have one of the default properties the default value will be used

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you can use *accessor properties* to do the parentheses part of what you're asking about. I wouldn't call it good practice in this situation (a function call should generally look like a function call, not a property access), but if you want to:

```js
function mainFunction(object){
    const first = object.date;
    console.log(first);
    while (object.date === first)
      ; // Busy loop for up to one millisecond
    console.log(object.date);
}

mainFunction({
    get date() {
        return Date.now();
    }
    // get string() { etc.
});
```

Notice how `object.date` triggers a *function call* to the `get` function for the `date` property on `object`, and so the value changes as the time changes.

I can't figure out the question about `varname`, but fundamentally `varname.mainFunction` with `varname` having the value `undefined` will always fail, and you can't do anything in `mainFunction` that will prevent that.